# Does endian act differently on different devices

Tags: android, endianness, audiorecord

I'm using `AudioRecord.read(byte[], int, int)` to record 16-bit PCM data. Using this method, I can get little endian data on my device but I don't know if it works on other devices. Although I saw API reference, I couldn't figure it out.

Does endian depend on native order?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about it, Android take care of it for you.

Data in java is always represented as big endian

Comment: Thanks. I know that but I have to convert data to short and have to write data to native process. So I have to care of it.

Comment: See out of java :) , but yes it would be big endian all of the time

Comment: Thanks but "all of the time" is wrong. Check my question again.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not as simple as the previous (3 year old) answer suggests.

If you use 16bit PCM, Android will have it native endian encoded. See [AudioFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioFormat.html#encoding). Testing showed that on a Nexus 5x it was BE, a Xiaomi MI3s reported LE.

To get the endianess of your device you can use `ByteOrder.nativeOrder()`